# What is the quickest and most efficient way to remove an in-memory filegroup from a large SQL Server 2019 database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory-optimized-tables

I have a database with a in-memory filegroup that I want to remove (I wont go into much details why, but I want to move the database to another place without this filegroup).
Notes:

- This is running SQL Server 2019
- This database is quite big: more than 500GB
- There is no data in that filegroup at this time
- It have tables (of course), views, SP, Synonyms...

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/the-memory-optimized-filegroup?view=sql-server-ver16) "Once you use a memory-optimized filegroup, you can only remove it by dropping the database.". So, I need to drop the database, and create it again without the file group. But doesn't detail the best way to do this.

What is the best option to do this?

I've tried the Copy Database Wizard but it copies the filegroup that I want to delete.

I've tried the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard but it takes too long. I've tried to export to another instance, but due to the size of the database it fails after several hours (network error or session lost).

I've tried to use the option "Generate Scripts" and do this:

1. Export schema only
2. Export data only
3. Edit the file to remove the filegroup
4. Drop the database
5. Recreate the database with the edited file
6. Import the data

But this is taking too long. There is any other way (best and quick way) to do this?